# Upsert does not work for updateOne bulkWrite v3.4

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to bulk write some updates and everything except the upsert is working.
My code is updating all items perfectly and no errors is given what so ever.
The issue here is that the bulk insert with `updateOne` is not upserting.

(This is an untested and shortened example of my code, so you might find some syntax errors. Hopefully you get the idea.)

```
async function insert(items) {
    const ops = items.map(item => ({
        updateOne: {
            filter: {
                id: item.id,
                country: item.country,
            },
            update: { $set: item },
            upsert: true
        }
    }));

    return await db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
}

insert([{
    id: '123',
    country: 'uk',
    email: 'test@test.com'
}]);
```

The snippet above does not upsert the missing items, but updates everything else correctly.

I'm using `node version 6.6.0` and `mongodb version v3.4.10` and accordingly to the mongodb documenation for 3.4 (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) the bulkwrite is *New in version 3.2.*

This snippet is from MongoDB 3.4 documenation for `bulkWrite`.

```
db.collection.bulkWrite( [
   { updateOne :
      {
         "filter" : <document>,
         "update" : <document>,
         "upsert" : <boolean>
      }
   }
] )
```

And this is an example from the same documentation.

```
{
    updateOne: {
        "filter": { "char": "Eldon" },
        "update": { $set: { "status": "Critical Injury" } }
    }
}
```

I've tried a normal update directly in the mongo terminal interface with the exact same data and an upserts the item correctly.

```
db.collection.update({ id: '123', country: 'uk' }, { $set: { id: '123', country: 'uk', email: 'test@test.com' } }, { upsert: true });
```

Comment: Can you try with: 

 const ops = items.map(item => ({
        updateOne: {
            filter: {
                id: item.id,
                country: item.country,
            },
            update: { $set: **{item}** },
            upsert: true
        }
    }));

Comment: Oh god, that actually worked?! Care to explain why in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
const ops = items.map(item => 
           ({ updateOne: { 
              filter: { id: item.id, country: item.country}, 
              update: { $set: {item} }, upsert: true } 
           }));
```

**$set** by syntax would expect **{ id: item.id, country: item.country}** than just  **id: item.id, country: item.country** being passed.