# MongoDB > Can I upsertMany using instance data in the query

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm currently attempting to synchronise data from an external source, into a Mongo database. The data comes in, as an array, and I'd like to BULK `insert` or `update` ("`upsert`") the data, depending on whether a record with a matching `customid` already exists.

```
var data = [{
    customid: '123',
    name: 'Bob',
    occupation: 'Builder'
}]

db.foobar.insertMany(data)
```

Insert is fine, but now (on subsequent synchronisations), I would like to `insert`/`update` the following (sample) data, not knowing if the `customid` exists... is there any way to do this as a bulk operation? e.g.

```
var newdata = [{
    customid: '123',
    name: 'Bob',
    occupation: 'Nightclub Bouncer'
}]

db.foobar.updateMany({ customid: $instance.customid }, newdata, { upsert: true })
```

... or is the only way, to manually iterate over the records and run an `update(..)`?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a compromise, using `bulkWrite` and multiple `updateOne` statements. If anyone has a better solution, please don't hesitate to post it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47832754/782034